# NEED TO SEARCH SL NOS BY USING 6 DIGIT NO FROM SEARCH AS INPUT FROM COLUMN AS VARCHAR 2 DATA TYPE

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table TASK1 (
SL_NO NUMBER ,
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2 (1000));


INSERT INTO TASK1 VALUES (1,'EMPLOYEE NO. (300546), EMPLOYEE NO T-4300546, EMPLOYEE NO 30054698TT ARE AWARDED AS EMPLOYEE OF THE MONTH IN APR22');

INSERT INTO TASK1 VALUES (2,'EMPLOYEE NO. (L300546), EMPLOYEE NO T-4300546K, EMPLOYEE NO GT30054698TT ARE AWARDED AS EMPLOYEE OF THE MONTH IN MAR22');

INSERT INTO TASK1 VALUES (3,'EMPLOYEE NO. (GT30056), EMPLOYEE NO T-4300546K, EMPLOYEE NO GT30054698TT ARE AWARDED AS EMPLOYEE OF THE MONTH IN FEB22');

INSERT INTO TASK1 VALUES (4,'EMPLOYEE NO. (-300546), EMPLOYEE NO T-4300546K, EMPLOYEE NO GT30054698TT ARE AWARDED AS EMPLOYEE OF THE MONTH IN JAN22');
```

I want to search all the sl no in which employee no 300546 is involved . i used like query for above result - select * from task1 where description like '%300546%'; but it is listing all SL no where 300546 not effected in sl no 3. (Note while searching special charecter, alphabet like (), L, -T may be there in data along with 300546).

thank you.

Comment: Out of your 4 rows, which would you not expect to come back with that criteria?

Comment: All caps is considered SHOUTING.  All the records contain a substring of "300546" including #3.

Comment: It sounds like you expect that #3 wouldn't match. While it isn't present inside parentheses  is does appear twice afterward.

Comment: I don't want sl no 3 in result@andrew.

Comment: there is a digit diffrence in sl no 3 . its 30056 instead of 300546 @oldprogrammer

Comment: yes #3 should not match@shawnt00

Comment: You seem to be overlooking the fact that there are still multiple places within each your descriptions where the number can match.

Answer (score 0):

With your current table structure and description you can use:

```
select * from task1 where description like '%(300546)%'
```

But that's a bit of a hack.  If you change anything about the description (add two emp numbers, or the parens aren't put it) that will no longer work.  You should consider adding the employee number as a separate column.  That way you'll be able to easily join for more employee information.

Comment: i am also in the same opinion but i am dealing with old data and i have to make a search module in existing data @egret

Answer (score 0):

> while searching special character, alphabet like (), L, -T may be there in data along with 300546

If it can be `EMPLOYEE NO. (` then an optional character and then the digits you want to match and then `)` then you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   task1
WHERE  description LIKE 'EMPLOYEE NO. (300546)%'
OR     description LIKE 'EMPLOYEE NO. (_300546)%'
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

> | SL_NO | DESCRIPTION |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | EMPLOYEE NO. (300546), EMPLOYEE NO T-4300546, EMPLOYEE NO 30054698TT ARE AWARDED AS EMPLOYEE OF THE MONTH IN APR22 |
> | 2 | EMPLOYEE NO. (L300546), EMPLOYEE NO T-4300546K, EMPLOYEE NO GT30054698TT ARE AWARDED AS EMPLOYEE OF THE MONTH IN MAR22 |
> | 4 | EMPLOYEE NO. (-300546), EMPLOYEE NO T-4300546K, EMPLOYEE NO GT30054698TT ARE AWARDED AS EMPLOYEE OF THE MONTH IN JAN22 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4c7a5fb7c268ed7b2662cd500ecba25a)*

Comment: i want to pass a employee no 300546 in search criteria and then the result should not come with #3 @MT0

Comment: @Jay #3 was not returned. If you want to pass in `300546` then split the strings up into `description LIKE 'EMPLOYEE NO. (' || :your_value || ')%' OR description LIKE 'EMPLOYEE NO. (_' || :your_value || ')%'`